# How do I return the value of start_date

Tags: podio

```
[11] => PodioDateItemField Object
  (
    [__attributes:PodioObject:private] => Array
      (
        [field_id] => 124463765
        [type] => date
        [external_id] => birthday-2
        [label] => Birthday
        [values] => Array
          (
            [0] => Array
              (
                [start] => 1980-01-15 00:00:00
                [start_date_utc] => 1980-01-15
                [start_time_utc] => 
                [start_time] => 
                [start_utc] => 1980-01-15
                [start_date] => 1980-01-15
              )
```

I have tried many variations of:

```
$mr_dob_data1 = $client->fields[11]->__attributes["values"][0]["start_date"];
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a PHP object, so you can access it like this:

`$mr_dob_data1 = $client->fields[11]->values[0]["start_date"];`

Comment: The return is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I knew it was a date field, here's the code that worked:

```
$mr_dob_data = date_format($client->fields[11]->values['start'], "d M Y");
```